# Sed with port forwarding in socat?

Tags: sed, telnet, socat

Not sure if this belongs on here, StackOverflow, or SuperUser.

I have a device running a reverse telnet server that I need to be able to send/receive data to. I'm able to play with it if I run socat like so and telnet into port 8002:

```
sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:8001 TCP-LISTEN:8002
```

However, it sends information it shouldn't, and I'm trying to use sed to filter this data out. I'd like this communication to remain bi-directional (that is, anything I type into telnet on localhost:8002 gets sent out through localhost:8001 and vise versa).

I've tried using a bash script containing:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
sed (my regex here) | socat - TCP-LISTEN:8002
```

and then running:

```
sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:8001 SYSTEM:./replace.sh
```

But that outputs nothing in the telnet console. I've also tried `EXEC:` to the same nothing happening.

I've even tried:

```
sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:8001 "SYSTEM:'sed (my regex here)' || TCP-LISTEN:8002"
```

to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing the `fork` bit. The command line would then be:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8002,fork SYSTEM:/path/to/replace.sh
```

then, the file /path/to/replace.sh should have the execution permission and could contain something like (this will change all 'a's to 'b's):

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -u 's/a/b/g'
```

If you are using sed, it is important to add the `-u` (unbuffered) flag.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! I was wondering how to go around sed's character buffering with this!